# Once page load , table content disappearing in IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I just created mvc 4 application to view table data set ,this is working fine in IE 9 , IE 10 , FireFox and Chrome .

but in IE 11 once page load its disappearing its whole row content

this is the view file

```
@model IEnumerable<AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.tbl_hec_University>

@{
    Page.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HEC_Dashboard.cshtml";
}

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="box box-primary">

                            <div class="box">

                                <div class="box-header">



                                    <div class="box-tools">
                                        <div class="input-group" style="width:50%; float:left;">
                                            <a class="editLink" href="@Url.Action("U_Create", "HEC", new { HEI_ID = @ViewBag.HEI_ID })"><button class="btn bg-red btn-flat margin"> <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> &nbsp; Add New University &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </button></a>
                                        </div>
                                     @using (Html.BeginForm("U_Search", "HEC", FormMethod.Get))
                                     {



                                    <div class="input-group" style="width:50%; float:right;">

                                        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control input-sm pull-right" style="width: 150px;" placeholder="Search" maxlength="25"/>
                                           <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                                           </div>

                                        </div>
                                     }

                                    </div>

                                 </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                                <!-- /.box-body -->

                                     <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">

            <table class="table table-hover" id="table-hover">
                <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th class="sortout">University ID</th>
                    <th class="sortout">University Name</th>
                    <th class="sortout">Established Year</th>
                    <th class="sortout">Type</th>
                    <th class="sortout">Status</th>
                   @* <th></th>*@

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              @if (Model.Count() != 0)
                {


                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
                    <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("U_Edit", "HEC", new { HEI_ID = item.HEI_ID }) '">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HEI_ID)
                    </td>
                    <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("U_Edit", "HEC", new { HEI_ID = item.HEI_ID }) '">
                     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HEI_Name) @*@Html.ActionLink(item.HEI_Name == null ? "NULL" : item.HEI_Name, "U_Edit", "HEC", new { HEI_ID = item.HEI_ID }, null)*@
                    </td>
                    <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("U_Edit", "HEC", new { HEI_ID = item.HEI_ID }) '">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year_Establish)
                    </td>
                    <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("U_Edit", "HEC", new { HEI_ID = item.HEI_ID }) '">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type_of_HEI)
                    </td>                                     


                </tr>
                    }

                }




            </tbody>

        </table>

         <div id="pager" style="margin:10px; position: none;">
            <form>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/first.png")" class="first" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/prev.png")" class="prev" />
            <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/next.png")" class="next" />
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/last.png")" class="last" />
            <select class="pagesize">
                <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>

                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
            </select>
            </form>
        </div>

             </div>



                            </div><!-- /.box -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>





<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".small-box.bg-aqua").addClass("Stborder");   

    });


</script>





@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(function () {
            $("#table-hover")
                .tablesorter({
                    widthFixed: true
                })
                .tablesorterPager({
                    container: $("#pager"),
                    size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val()
                });
        });

 </script>  


}
```

these are the files I Render from Script Folder

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/ionicons.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/morris.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/datepicker3.css")        
@Styles.Render("~/Content/daterangepicker-bs3.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/AdminLTE.css")



@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/raphael-min.js")        
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/morris.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js")    
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.knob.js")        
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/daterangepicker.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js")       
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/icheck.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/dashboard.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/demo.js")


@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")     
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.placeholder.min.js")
```

Is this jquery issue or error in my code ?

really appreciate if someone can show the path

Comment: Did you got any errors in Console (F12 developer tools)?

Comment: You've got quite a lot of code there, including lots of custom js scripts.  Try to remove parts that do not cause the problem (ie remove something (eg raphael-min.js) then check if problem still occurs, repeat - if it fixes, put that part back and remove something else) until you get down to the minimum that is causing the problem.  This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ramiramilu yes Im getting "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error"